# Program never ends when use other implementation of Execution Context for Futures

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool, future

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

object Test extends App {

  println("start")

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  val future: Future[Unit] = Future {
    println(s"future")
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }

  future.onComplete({
    case Success(x) => println("Success")
    case Failure(x) => println("Failure")
  })

  Await.result(future, 10 seconds)

  println("finish")

}
```

and the ouput is:

```
start
future
finish
Success
```

... but the program never ends

This is happening because I am using other Execution Context implementation, when I use `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` everything is fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you willing to call `shutdown` manually on the execution context? Because that should work.

Comment: Thank you, works! Now my question is: Is this the right way?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the program does not shut down is because of the way the `ExecutionContext` was initialized:

```
ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
```

This creates a pool of 10 threads via the defaultThreadFactory which creates non daemon threads:

> [Each new thread is created as a non-daemon thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory())

Unterminated non-daemon threads will prevent the JVM from exiting. You either need to provide a `ThreadFactory` that creates daemonthreads, or manually call `shutdown` on the `Executor` you created your `ExecutionContext` from.